# Ordering Inputs vertically using orderInput() function from shinyqui R Package

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to order the input in a vertical order not horizontal using `orderInput()` function from `shinyqui` R Package.

In the package and function documentation i could not find anything about that.

```
library(shinyjqui)
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$order <- renderPrint({input$foo})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  orderInput(inputId = 'foo', label = 'A simple example', items = c('A', 'B', 'C')),
  verbatimTextOutput('order')
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: add `class = "btn-group-vertical"` in the call to `orderInput`.